# Rendezvous with RestKit operations

Tags: ios, restkit, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I am trying to set up a quite complex chain of RestKit operations. First I have to make a request to a list of parent objects (let's call it parentRequestOperation), and for each parent objects in the list I have to create another request operation to fetch related objects (let's call them childRequestOperation). Obviously I can create childRequestOperations only in the success() block of parentRequestOperation as I do not know before how many and with which details should I create them.

I would like to have some feedback when all operations finished. For this purpose I created an NSOperation instance with my handling block (let's call it finishedOperation), added a dependency towards parentRequest to it, and added to the operationQueue of my RKObjectManager.

My problem is how to make a "rendezvous" between childRequestOperations and finishedOperation. I tried to add the dependency towards childRequestOperation to finishedOperation right after I create childRequestOperation (still in the success block of parentRequestOperation). But the problem is that RestKit calls the success block asynchronously in a different dispatch queue from the operationQueue of RKObjectManager, so as soon as parentRequestOperation finishes, the finishedOperation is fired before I could add the new dependency towards childRequestOperation.

What is the best practice to set up finishedOperation in a similar scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at setting the `successCallbackQueue` for the operations to use and also pushing your own tasks onto that same queue when your existing dependent operations are executed. If the queue you use is serial then you can guarantee the order of execution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a look at successCallbackQueue but unfortunately it is not an NSOperationQueue but a dispatch_queue_t and I could not figure out how to schedule NSOperations on dispatch queues (I guess it is not possible since they are not compatible).

Comment: You can't schedule operations on a GCD queue, only blocks using `dispatch_...` (but you could add these blocks to the queue from within your operations...)

Comment: The problem is that RestKit calls the successBlock asynchronously (in RKObjectRequestOperation.m: `dispatch_async(self.successCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ success(self, self.mappingResult); });`) so whatever I try to do in the successBlock happens after the RKObjectRequestOperation finished.

Comment: `dispatch_async` just adds the block to the queue and returns, it's the order that the blocks are added to the queue that is important.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunately I could add the new blocks to the queue only when the successBlock is effectively executing since I do not have the necessary info needed to create the new blocks before. How could the new blocks precede the successBlock?

Comment: Maybe we should look at something different entirely and just keep a counter of the tasks to be completed, then the count becomes zero you know you're done and you can trigger your completion logic...

Comment: In fact exactly the same solution I came up meanwhile. I'll post it soon as an answer. Thank you for your thinking together in all case.

Comment: Why not use recursion?

Answer (score 0):

At last I came up with a slightly out-of-the box solution. It is an NSObject subclass extended with a resource counter semaphore. This operation is executed only when the semaphore hits the zero.

**SemaphoreDependencyOperation.h**

```
@interface SemaphoreDependencyOperation : NSOperation

@property (atomic, readonly) int32_t dependencySemaphore;

-(void)incrementDependencySemaphore;
-(void)decrementDependencySemaphore;

@end
```

**SemaphoreDependencyOperation.m**

```
#import "SemaphoreDependencyOperation.h"
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

@implementation SemaphoreDependencyOperation

-(void)incrementDependencySemaphore
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"dependencySemaphore"];
    OSAtomicIncrement32(&_dependencySemaphore);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dependencySemaphore"];
}

-(void)decrementDependencySemaphore
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"dependencySemaphore"];
    OSAtomicDecrement32(&_dependencySemaphore);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dependencySemaphore"];
}

+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"dependencySemaphore"];
}

-(BOOL)isReady
{
    return [super isReady] && _dependencySemaphore <= 0;
}

@end
```

And usage:

```
SemaphoreDependencyOperation* trackerOperation = [[UpdateTrackerOperation alloc] init];
[trackerOperation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Everything done"); 
}];

NSURLRequest* parentRequest = // ...
RKObjectRequestOperation* parentRequestOperation =
  [self.objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:parentRequest
                                                success:
  ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) 
  {
    // create childRequestOperations based on mappingResult
    for (MyObject* myObject in [mappingResult array]) 
    {
       NSURLRequest* childRequest = // ... create it from myObject
       RKObjectRequestOperation* childRequestOperation = 
         [self.objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:parentRequest
                                                       success:
         ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) 
         {
           // ...
           [trackerOperation decrementDependencySemaphore];
         }
                                                       failure:nil];

         [self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:childRequestOperation];
         [trackerOperation incrementDependencySemaphore];
    }
    [trackerOperation decrementDependencySemaphore];
  }
                                                failure:nil];

[self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:parentRequestOperation];
[trackerOperation incrementDependencySemaphore];
[self.objectManager.operationQueue addOperation:trackerOperation];
```